# Can someone please explain the working of the function?

Tags: python

This was a basic selection sort alg in python.. I just defined another function to swap the elements
Here it does **not** work-

```
def swp(a, b):
    tmp = a
    a = b
    b = tmp
def selsor(arr):
    n=len(arr)-1
    for i in range(n):
        j=i+1
        m=i
        while(j<=n):
            if(arr[j]<arr[m]):
                m=j
            j=j+1
        swp(arr[m],arr[i])
```

but when I make following changes, it works-

```
def swp(a, b):
    tmp = a
    a = b
    b = tmp
    return a,b
def selsor(arr):
    n=len(arr)-1
    for i in range(n):
        j=i+1
        m=i
        while(j<=n):
            if(arr[j]<arr[m]):
                m=j
            j=j+1
        arr[m],arr[i]=swp(arr[m],arr[i])
```

I just don't understand why the swp() function is not changing the array elements by itself and have to make it return the elements and have to assign it again... For ex. the array itself gets changed as I pass it through the selsor() function. Why can't the swp() also work the same way?

Comment: `swp()` doesn't do anything. It's assigning local variables, which has no effect on the caller's variables.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You can just change it to `def swp(a, b): return b, a` you don't need the `tmp` variable.

Comment: And you don't need `swp` at all: `arr[m], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[m]` works just fine.